multi omics analysis using cytoscape
I would like to use cytoscape to do multi omics analysis of transcriptomics, proteomics and metabolomics. Can someone explain me how to do that?
Thank you,
Hashan

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This question seems too broad to get useful answers. Please add more context; is there a specific think that you're trying to do?

Note, there has been one request to close the question

General information about the use of Cytoscape can be found on the Cytoscape wiki:
https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape-tutorials/wiki
